# Coding theory in group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, coding-theory, group-rings

I am doing some extra practice problems and I got stuck on this one:

> Show that every element in the group ring $Z_2 C_n$ with even support (i.e. $wt(u)$ is even) is a zero-divisor. (Hint: Show that $1 + g$ divides $u$).

Why does the hint show this? How might I start?

Comment: What Nicky Hekster says. Also, does anything about 
$$\frac{1-g^n}{1-g}$$ ring a bell?

Comment: Okay, I understand how to show that 1+g divides u. However, why does this show that u is a zero-divisor? For some reason I can't see the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: look at the ring homomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[C_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, defined by $\varphi(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}g^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}$ (where $\langle g\rangle=C_n$). Then the ideal $(1+g) \subseteq ker(\varphi)$. But the reverse inclusion is also true: if $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}=0$, then consider the polynomial $f(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}X^i \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since $f(1)=0$, $f$ has a factor $X-1=X+1$. Hence $(1+g)=ker(\varphi)$.